# If $x^m + y^m = z^m$ has no solutions and $m \mid n$, then $x^n + y^n = z^n$ has no solutions

Tags: number-theory

We know from Fermat's Last Theorem that $x^n + y^n = z^n$ has no solutions for $n\geq 3$, but if we assume we did not know FLT, how could you prove that 
                          $x^n + y^n = z^n$
has no solutions if we know 
                          $x^m$ + $y^m$ $\neq$ $z^m$ 
and $m \mid n$? It seems obvious from just looking at the statement along with the information given, however I am unsure how it could be shown?

Comment: How is it obvious? Would it also be obvious without $m\mid n$? IIf no, you should be able to formulate why the former *is* obvious, arriving at a proof.

Answer (score 7):

Write $n=mk$ and suppose that $x^n+y^n=z^n$. Then $(x^k)^m + (y^k)^m = (z^k)^m$, so $(x^k,y^k,z^k)$ is a solution to $x^m+y^m=z^m$.